# GridView_RowUpdating not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have Gridview with ItemTemplate and EditItemTemplate:

But when i click "Ok" button, nothing happens. I tried to put trace point on RowUpdating event and click "Ok" button, but its not even triggered. I assume, that problem could be in the same "Id" of ItemTemplate and EditItemTemplate lbl_first_fl. But earlier this worked fine, the only thing was changed - i updated Visual studio to 2015 and changed Windows to 8. So i installed VS 2013, but problem still occures. Any suggestions? Or maybe how can i deal with it using different id's?

aspx page:

```html
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView5" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" Height="430px" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView5_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowDataBound="GridView5_RowDataBound" OnRowEditing="GridView5_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView5_RowUpdating" Width="100%" CssClass="gridview" GridLines="none">
                                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />

                                <Columns>

  <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="100">
<EditItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Button ID="btn_Update_fl" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Ок" />
<asp:Button ID="btn_Cancel_fl" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Отмена" />
</EditItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
 <asp:Button ID="btn_Edit_fl" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="✎" Enabled='<%# Flag %>' />
</ItemTemplate>

</asp:TemplateField>

 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="08:00 - 17:00" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">                                                                                                        
<ItemTemplate>
 <asp:Label ID="lbl_first_fl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("First") %>' Visible="true"></asp:Label>                                                                                                                   
 </ItemTemplate>

 <EditItemTemplate>
 <asp:Label ID="lbl_first_fl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("First") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>        
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_first_fl" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList> 
                                                       
</EditItemTemplate>

</asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:CommandField/>
                                              

</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

OnRowUpdating event:

```
 protected void GridView5_RowUpdating(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {


        DropDownList First_fl = GridView5.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ddl_first_fl") as DropDownList;



        con = new SqlConnection(cs);
        con.Open();
        //updating the record  
        SqlCommand cmd_fl = new SqlCommand("Update [Duty].[dbo].[Schedule_FirstLine] set First='" + First_fl.Text + "', con);
        cmd_fl.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();

        GridView5.EditIndex = -1;

        ShowDataFirstLine();

    }
```

Binding Gridview:

```
 protected void ShowDataFirstLine()
    {
        DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(Calendar1.VisibleDate.Date.ToString());

        var firstDayOfMonth = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1);
        var lastDayOfMonth = firstDayOfMonth.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);

        string GridDS_FirstLine = "set dateformat dmy  Select DutyDate,WeekDay,First, Second from [Duty].[dbo].[Schedule_FirstLine] WHERE DutyDate >= '" + firstDayOfMonth + "' AND DutyDate <= '" + lastDayOfMonth + "'";

        dt_FirstLine = new DataTable();
        con_FirstLine = new SqlConnection(cs);
        con_FirstLine.Open();
        adapt_FirstLine = new SqlDataAdapter(GridDS_FirstLine, con_FirstLine);
        adapt_FirstLine.Fill(dt_FirstLine);
        if (dt_FirstLine.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            GridView5.DataSource = dt_FirstLine;
            GridView5.DataBind();
        }

        GridView5.Columns[0].Visible = true;
    }
```

Comment: could you post gridview tag from aspx page

Comment: ok, on clicking update button your row should be updated right?

Comment: Right. But code in RowUpdating event not firing at all.

Comment: Fine.Where did you post for binding gridview?

Comment: this code is for binding dropdown..i need code for binding gridview

Comment: Added binding method.

Comment: okay.. where you are binding this method .. ?

Comment: you should bind this page_load event with if condition **if(!postback)**

Comment: I bind it on page_load with if(!postback) condition. Then i bind it in RowUpdating event. But i don't understand how this can help me, because the problem is not, that updated info in Gridview is missing. My sclcommand, that updates data in database, not fires in RowUpdating. I think problem is earlier, before the binding event.

Comment: so from this rowupdating method is firing right ?

Comment: unfortunately no, nothing fires from rowupdating. Binding fires once, from page_load. Story: after page_load I see data in Gridview, then i click "Edit", choose some value from DropDownList, press "Ok", and nothing happens

Comment: try giving causesvalidation as false in update button

Comment: I get the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You name the event on the grid like this?

```
<asp:GridView ID="TaskGridView" runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateEditButton="True" 
        AllowPaging="true"
        OnRowEditing="TaskGridView_RowEditing"         
        OnRowCancelingEdit="TaskGridView_RowCancelingEdit" 
        OnRowUpdating="TaskGridView_RowUpdating"
        OnPageIndexChanging="TaskGridView_PageIndexChanging">
      </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Yes. Sorry, i updated my question just now, and added gridview properties.